# Upload file using MVC 2 and need to works in IE 8 and 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to upload a excel file with ajax now, but I try a lot of things.
Ajax, jquery, submit, etc and I can't refresh page.

My big problem is need to work in IE 8 and IE 9. because of this I can't use formdata.

Now i trying this way.

--Html--

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="MyLink" enctype="multipart/form-data"                     method="post">
  <input type="file" id="fileExcel" name="fileExcel"> 
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit"                                                                          onclick="javascript:functionPost()" value="Import!">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidIdNeed1" name="hidIdNeed1" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidIdNeed2" name="hidIdNeed2" value="1"></form>
```

--javascript--

```
function functionPost()
```

{
  var form = $("#MyForm");

$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "my url",
          data: form.serializeArray(),
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
          success: function(response) {
                       $("#Result").html(response);
                   }
        });
}

Controller C#:
I was using, but this way I cant take a file.

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase
```

to take a file, but this way I cant take a file and Request.Files

How is the best way to do this?